# I want to reshape a dataframe to look differently such that the rows become columns but unable to do so

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame looks like this :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'0':['USA'],
                   '1':['UK'],
                   '2':['UAE']})
```

I want the reshaped dataframe to look like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['USA','UK','UAE'],
                   'Prob':['0','1','2']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `values` attribute you can extract underlying numpy array storing actual data of your DataFrame and use it to build a new DataFrame. `ravel()` function flattens original 2D array with a single row to 1D array so that you can build a column out of it. The whole DataFrame can be built as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country':df.values.ravel(), 'Prob':df.columns.values})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it in this way but i was wondering if there is a way to do it with melt and reshape:

`cols1 = df.iloc[0]`

`df_cols1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country':cols1})`

`cols2 = list(df.columns)`

`df_cols2 = pd.DataFrame({'Prob':cols2})`

`df_cols1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

`df_cols2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

`df1 = pd.concat([df_cols1,df_cols2], axis=1)`

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try `transpose`, `assign`, and `rename`

```
df.T.assign(Prob=df.columns).rename(columns={0: 'Country'})

Out[63]:
  Country Prob
0     USA    0
1      UK    1
2     UAE    2
```